# Nexus Repository Manager stuck in 'Storage facet cleanup' loop

Tags: containers, openshift, nexus

I've been stuck in this loop for a few days now. I've tried running different version of Nexus (3.37.0, 3.37.1, 3.37.2, 3.37.3) and restarting the deployment through OpenShift multiple times.

It was working normally for months until February 6th, then I lost access to the web console and my repository mirrors became inaccessible.

I've searched the site multiple times and haven't found anything that's worked so far.

Some of the nexus logs are below, but it has just repeated going from `RUNNING` to `WAITING (OK)` for days so I clipped them:

```
-------------------------------------------------

Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.37.3-02

-------------------------------------------------
2022-02-07 18:10:00,021+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2022-02-07 18:10:00,041+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2022-02-07 18:20:00,011+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-2] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2022-02-07 18:20:00,018+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-2] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2022-02-07 18:30:00,007+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-3] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2022-02-07 18:30:00,013+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-3] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
...
...
...
2022-02-09 19:50:00,003+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-20] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2022-02-09 19:50:00,008+0000 INFO  [quartz-9-thread-20] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
```

Comment: Those log messages don’t have anything to do with your issue, that is a background task that runs every 10 minutes.  Those messages are normal.

Comment: I'll edit the post with the rest of the log as well, not sure why it would suddenly become unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out my OpenShift service was only connecting to deployments with a particular name `nexus-2` and the current deployment was `nexus-3`. I removed that filter, and I was able to access it again. Thanks to @rseddon for pointing out that this log was not in fact the problem, prompting me to look for the answer elsewhere.